# how to do addition of two 2d arrays and store and display them in 3rd array using function?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, addition

I've just started learning C language.

I have started the topic of arrays and now I'm confused as to how to add two 2D arrays and store and display them in a third 2D array using a function...

PS. I am attaching the code which I mentioned above.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void displayA1(int a[3][3])
{
    printf("\n The 1st Array is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void displayB1(int b[3][3])
{
    printf("\n The 2nt Array is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", b[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int doAdd(int a[3][3], int b[3][3], int c[3][3])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int a[3][3];
    int b[3][3];
    int c[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the Elements: ");
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n****************************\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the Elements: ");
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    displayA1(a);
    displayB1(b);
    int sum = doAdd(a, b, c);

    printf("\n\n The Addition of two Arrays is: %d ", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a program but it turns out to show the sum of individual elements of both the arrays.

Would be glad to receive help.

Comment: You are passing the result array as an argument to function `doAdd()`, but `doAdd()` never accesses the corresponding parameter.  Don't you think there's something odd about that?

Comment: `doAdd()` accumulates a sum of *all* the elements of `a` and `b`, and returns it.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but it hasn't much to do with an element-wise sum array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints to improve your program and solve your problem:

- You should factorize the code in `displayA1` and `displayB1`, which only differ in the message printed.
- Similarly, you could use a function to read the elements of a matrix and call it for `a` and `b`, avoiding error prone code replication.
- The function `doAdd` should store the sums of individual matrix elements into the third matrix.
- The `main` function should display the third matrix with the results.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_matrix(const char *name, int a[3][3])
{
    printf("\nEnter the elements of matrix %s:\n", name);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("Enter the element %s[%d][%d]: ", name, i, j);
            if (scanf("%d", &a[i][j]) != 1) {
                printf("invalid input\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}

void display_matrix(const char *name, const int a[3][3])
{
    printf("\nThe matrix %s is:\n", name);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf(" %4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int doAdd(const int a[3][3], const int b[3][3], int c[3][3])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            sum = sum + c[i][j]
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[3][3];
    int b[3][3];
    int c[3][3];

    input_matrix("a", a);
    input_matrix("b", b);

    display_matrix("a", a);
    display_matrix("b", b);

    int sum = doAdd(a, b, c);

    display_matrix("c", c);
    printf("\n\nThe sum of elements is: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the result of `a[i][j] + b[i][j]` to `c[i][j]` in order to make the result of the individual additions available outside of the `doAdd` function.

Example:

```c
int doAdd(const int a[3][3], const int b[3][3], int c[3][3]) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            sum += c[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

And you also need to actually print the result in `main` after calling `doAdd`.

```c
void display(const char* heading, const int a[3][3]) {
    puts(heading);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void) {
    //...
    int sum = doAdd(a, b, c);

    printf("\n\n The Addition of two Arrays is: %d ", sum);

    display("The resulting array is:", c);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fr8W9feYG)

Comment: I did so but still it is not displaying the sum as an Array , rather it is still showing the sum

Comment: you can call this displayA1(c); or displayB1(c) ; after this line int sum = doAdd(a,b,c); in main func to display the sum of individual elements.

Comment: @RahulDeshmukh I added the missing part to the answer.

Comment: It is Working now !! just one tiny problem is that when it returns the sum it displays the first printf statement of Array 1 , how do I solve that

Comment: @RahulDeshmukh I'm a bit unsure what you mean, but I added a demo to the answer.

Comment: When I am using display for printing the C array the error of "undefined reference to display" is showing  , But if I use displayA1(c);  It will print the C array but it also prints The printf statement of Function displayA1()  , i.e "The First Array is: "

Comment: @RahulDeshmukh Please look at the demo

Comment: Yes Yes I Did , in my Compiler which is Code Blocks it throws off that Error

Comment: Then you did not implement `display` the way I showed it in the answer (and in the demo).